# Foreach in PDO query to build HAVING statement

Tags: php, pdo

I'm converting old queries to PDO prepared statements, however I'm stuck on part of a dynamic query that uses a foreach loop to populate an unknown amount of conditions.

Here's an example of this part of the query (the values being multiple):

> HAVING  SUM(li.MSAttributeValID IN (5)) > 0 AND
> SUM(li.MSAttributeValID IN (224,234,240)) > 0

and the code which generates it by cycling through an array:

```
if($filterArray['Attributes']){
        $this->sql_part_2 .= " having ";
        foreach($filterArray['Attributes'] as $attID => $attValueArray){
            if($attID == array_key_first($filterArray['Attributes'])){
                $this->sql_part_2 .= " SUM(";
            }
            $this->sql_part_2 .= "li.MSAttributeValID IN (";
            foreach($attValueArray as $attValueID => $attValue){
                $this->sql_part_2 .= "$attValue";
                if($attValueID != array_key_last($attValueArray)){
                    $this->sql_part_2 .= ",";
                }else{
                    $this->sql_part_2 .= ")) > 0";
                }
            }
            if($attID != array_key_last($filterArray['Attributes'])){
                $this->sql_part_2 .= " AND SUM(";
            }
        }
    }
```

$filterArray:

```
[Attributes] => Array
            (
                [82] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 6
                        [1] => 7
                    )

                [85] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 231
                    )

            )
```

How would I set parameters in this instance? Can I just do a count on the variable within the loop? No idea where to start, what should I be reading up on to cover this scenario? Thank-you.

Bind/Execute by:

```
    $sql_results = $pdo->prepare($this->select_products_sql.$this->sql_part_1.$this->sql_part_1a.$this->sql_group.$this->sql_part_2.$this->sql_sort.$limit);

    $sql_results->bindValue(':CategoryID', $this->SubCategoryID);
    $sql_results->bindValue(':PriceMin', $PriceMin);
    $sql_results->bindValue(':PriceMax', $PriceMax);
    $sql_results->bindValue(':limitFrom', $limitFrom, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql_results->bindValue(':limitTo', $limitTo, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $sql_results->execute();

    $results = $sql_results->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what `$filterArray['Attributes']` looks like?

Comment: Hi Grumpy, I've added an example to my thread.

Comment: Is it _always_ 2 sets of data?

Comment: Nope, it's a unspecified amount, can be 1,2,3,4.... depending on criteria selected by end user.

Comment: So for each data set, it needs it's own `SUM()`?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: One more thing. Can you show us the line(s) of code where you are actually preparing and executing the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do what you want. For each set of data, it will create a new placeholder and bind the value for you.
I've done my best to comment lines to give you a better understanding of what is going on.

```
if($filterArray['Attributes']){
    
    //create an empty array which will eventually hold each SUM() call for your query
    $attributes = [];
    
    //create an empty array to hold values you need to bind with the placeholder as the key
    $attribute_binds = [];
    
    //loop through all sets of attributes
    foreach($filterArray['Attributes'] as $key => $values) {
        
        // ... for each set of attributes
        
        //create empty array for placeholder names
        $placeholders = [];
        
        //loop through each value of set
        foreach($values as $key2 => $value) {
            
            //create a placeholder name unique to this attribute data
            //e.g `attribute_82_0` based on keys of each data set
            //by using array keys this way, each placeholder will be unique
            //add placeholder name and value to $attribute_binds array
            //add placeholder name to $placeholders array
            $placeholder_name = ":attribute_{$key}_{$key2}";
            $attribute_binds[$placeholder_name] = $value;
            $placeholders[] = $placeholder_name;
        }
        
        //implode $placeholders array to be a comma separated list
        $placeholders = implode(', ', $placeholders);
        
        //add completed attribute SUM() call to $attributes array
        $attributes[] = "SUM(li.MSAttributeValID IN ({$placeholders})) > 0";
    }
    
    //implode all SUM() calls to your query
    $this->sql_part_2 .= implode(' AND ', $attributes);
}

//later in the script, prepare and bind values
$sql_results = $pdo->prepare($this->select_products_sql.$this->sql_part_1.$this->sql_part_1a.$this->sql_group.$this->sql_part_2.$this->sql_sort.$limit);

$sql_results->bindValue(':CategoryID', $this->SubCategoryID);
$sql_results->bindValue(':PriceMin', $PriceMin);
$sql_results->bindValue(':PriceMax', $PriceMax);
$sql_results->bindValue(':limitFrom', $limitFrom, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql_results->bindValue(':limitTo', $limitTo, PDO::PARAM_INT);

//bind attribute values
foreach($attribute_binds as $placeholder => $value) {
    $sql_results->bindValue($placeholder, $value);
}

$sql_results->execute();
```

In the code above, the following string will be appended to `$this->sql_part_2` given your sample data, and the values will be binded to the unique placeholder name.

```
SUM(li.MSAttributeValID IN (:attribute_82_0, :attribute_82_1)) > 0 AND SUM(li.MSAttributeValID IN (:attribute_85_0)) > 0
```

Comment: Hi @GrumpyCrouton, great reply, thanks a lot, that makes sense I just don't understand how to bind values to this as I don't usually do ? placeholders. I've edited my original post with the bind/execute part, thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank for your patience with this, it is making sense! I'm assuming "$vals" needs to be $filterArray['Attributes'] and then how do I bindValue BEFORE I prepare? Because the prepare is a combination of variables and not SQL, I need it at the end. So the $sql_results for the bindValue in this loop is undefined.

Comment: @nicksource Check my update again. I changed a few things